# BrowserAuthError:uninitialized_public_client_application . Getting this error when trying SSO with MSAL for React and Next.js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, msal-react, app-route

Iam creating a React application with `Next.js` 14 and `App router`. Iam trying `single Sign On (SSO)` using Azure Msal.

I have created my Msal.ts which has MSAL configuration which iam using it my `layout.tsx` which is a wrapper for my web application.

When i tried to trigger `Login`., i see following error

`BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.`

This is my `Msal.ts` code:

```
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  Configuration,
  LogLevel,
} from "@azure/msal-browser";

const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID || "default-client-id", // Azure AD client id
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`, // zure AD tenant id
    redirectUri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_REDIRECT_URL, // app redirect URL
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "/", // app logout URL
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // If you are having issues on IE11, you may need to set this to true
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
        }
      },
      logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
    },
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export default msalInstance;
```

This `Msal.ts`., iam importing it to my `Layout.tsx`:

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Box, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { AppStore, makeStore, persistor } from "@/lib/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import Leftsidebar from "./components/Leftsidebar";
import msalInstance from "@/lib/Msal";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    const accounts = await msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    console.log("accounts", accounts);
    return accounts.length > 0;
  };

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathName = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      const auth = await isAuthenticated();
      // restrict unauthorized users to access inner pages
      if (!auth && pathName !== "/") {
        router.push("/");
      }
      // restrict authorized users to signout before login again
      if (auth && pathName === "/") {
        router.push("/dashboard");
      }
    };
    checkAuth();
  }, [pathName, msalInstance]);

  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current.__persistor}>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
              <Grid container sx={{ backgroundColor: "#F8F8F9" }}>
                <Grid item xs={true}>
                {children}
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is my `handleLoginClick` functionality:

```
const handleLoginClick = async () => {
  // msalInstance.loginRedirect();
  try {
    const loginRequest = {
      scopes: ["openId", "profile", "User.Read"],
    };
    await msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
    const accountInfo = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
    if (accountInfo) {
      console.log("accountInfo", accountInfo);
      const stateData = {
        message: "Dashboard page",
        loggedinUser: accountInfo,
      };
      dispatch(setDashboardData(stateData));
      router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  
};
```

I believe this is issue with asynchronous behaviour with `Next.js`. Not sure where to make changes for it to work. Can you help me with what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed is asynchronous behaviours issue. in your `layout.tsx`., you need to `initialize` msalInstance before calling it. This will ensure `msalInstance` is ready.

Here is the updated code:

```js
const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    await msalInstance.initialize(); // Add this line
    const accounts = await msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    console.log("accounts", accounts);
    return accounts.length > 0;
  };
```